# copying one row to another based on value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy my data from one sheet to another depending on the column value. I had the below code running but due to some reason, I could see the column pasted from 52 row.

I wanted to have them pasted in the 2row of the sheet everytime. Could someone help where I am wring with the code ?

```
Sub list()
Dim cell As Range
Dim nextrow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In Sheets("BW").Range("T5:T" & Sheets("BW").Cells(Sheets("BW").Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row)
If cell.Value = "1" Then
nextrow = Sheets("PSW").Cells(Sheets("PSW").Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
Rows(cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("PSW").Range("A" & nextrow + 1)
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried everytime checking the column T, if it is one in my sheet BW , I paste the complete row to the sheet PSW It is everytime getting pasted from 52 row. Pleasehelp me to resolve this

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish, and I think if you provided sample data (showing what you get vs. what you want) that would help.  I tried your code on some test data and it appears designed to 1) define a range of values from T5 to the end of column T in the PW sheet, 2) look for any cell in that range that has a "1" in it, 3) then copy that row to the row in the PSW sheet corresponding to the end of the T column on the PSW sheet.  If row 52 is the only row with a "1" in it, that's the only row that will get copied.

Comment: No.. it looks for the column T. Whichever row has 1 it copies the complete row to next sheet...the problem here is u get the row copied in sheet 2 from row 52. I want them from row 2 in sht 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check your `PSW` sheet whether `T` column has existing data.

or You can use CountA for better clarity than using `Cells(Sheets("BW").Rows.Count, "T")` for getting the row number.

```
Sub list()
Dim cell As Range
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim a As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
a = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("BW").Range("T:T"))
For Each cell In Sheets("BW").Range("T5:T" & a)
If cell.Value = "1" Then
nextrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("PSW").Range("T:T"))
Rows(cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("PSW").Range("A" & nextrow + 1)
End If

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I have not enough points to add comments so i posted as answer.

Comment: I will have a look at this .. and to be clear. I always clear the sheet contents before copying to the next sheet

Comment: Check my code and let us know if you stuck somewhere.

Comment: Perfect It worked :) But can you tell me what was the bug in my code ?

Comment: Well i have not the data you are working with so i can test your code basis cell(row,column) so i just used excel worksheet function . your code should work too but with our your data i cant tell you whats the bug :)